# How can I change file permissions on Jelly Bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, files, file-permissions

My rooted Galaxy Nexus is on Jelly Bean (4.1.1) with a super user application. I want to install sinhala font into the phone, and for that I've tried to copy the font file (droidfallbackcens.ttf) to the font folder in my phone using the root explorer app. But it says that I have only read permissions on my phone.

I have googled this issue and tried several methods *(most of those methods were about ICS)*, but I haven't been able to change file permissions to get "read write execute", can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to remount your file system to enable write. I'm not sure how that's done with Root Explorer, but from the Terminal it looks something like:

```
mount -o rw,remount /partition/name/
```

*You can get the partition name by typing `mount` without any parameters.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Speed Software Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) application then you might be holding your phone wrong! -**guffaws**

No really! When I hold the phone in portrait view I can't get access to the little button in the interface that puts that directory into R/W mode (Read/Write):

[image: Portrait view, no button]

Hold your phone in landscape view when you navigate to that folder. When you get there you will see the little button to 'Mount R/W':

[image: Landscape view, button present]

Remember to turn it back to 'Mount R/O' (Read/Only)

*If this doesn't fix your issue then I will wonder if you actually have root access. Just saying...*

Good luck (: